# Assert Capybara table data

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec, capybara, e2e-testing

The app I am testing shows a lot of tables with multiple columns. Each table shows data that the app fetches from different data sources(csv files) which have been imported into a SQL database. I am doing this in my capybara UI test:

```
expect(data_for_row(student)).to match expected_data
```

For expected data: Is it best that I parse the csv files and build expected data set? FYI - files are huge and may change every 2-3 months. If so, what's the most efficient way to write such tests? There are going to be multiple files and huge in size(thousands of rows). Each table might show data from different files at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're actually trying to test.  If you're just trying to test the app displays whats been imported into the database correctly then you'd just do that with your own test data CSVs in whatever size you feel like and it wouldn't really need to change (unless the app changes obviously)

However, if you're running a sanity test against the live system to make sure it's showing the correct data then you're going to need to parse the CSV files in your test and pick a small number of rows to verify their displayed data is valid.